# Cumulative sum/subtraction dependent on flag and account number R

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a data set that looks

```
TransAmount   C/D   ACCOUNT BALANCE  NEW_BAL
110            C    500000  130.34  -6128.74
200            D    500000  130.34  -6328.74
210            C    500000  130.34
83.07          C    500009  -1079   -6411.81
113.49         C    500026  112.63  -6525.3
39.74          C    500041  179.2   -6565.04
39.74          C    500041  179.2   -6604.78
80             D    500051  -959.93 -6684.78
```

The New_Bal is being worked out wrong here.

I want the NEW_BAL to be worked out at Account level.

So, if it's the first instance of that ACCOUNT and the C/D is C then the New_Bal = BALANCE-TRANSAMOUNT

If the C/D is D then New_Bal = BALANCE+TRANSAMOUNT

For all other instances of that Account I want to use the previous New_Bal instead of BALANCE. For all other instances of each account, if C/D = C then the New_Bal = New_Bal(from previous version) -TRANSAMOUNT

If the C/D is D then New_Bal = New_Bal(from previous version) +TRANSAMOUNT

My desired output is:

```
TransAmount   C/D   ACCOUNT BALANCE  NEW_BAL
110            C    500000  130.34  20.34
200            D    500000  130.34  220.34
210            C    500000  130.34  10.34
83.07          C    500009  -1079   -1162.07
113.49         C    500026  112.63  -0.86
39.74          C    500041  179.2   139.46
39.74          C    500041  179.2   99.72
80             D    500051  -959.93 -879.93
```

Please note that 2 is not the maximum number of transactions, there can be up to 40 so I want NEW_BAL to be a rolling balance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have written makes sense? Maybe re-read it and clarify please?

Comment: @StephenHenderson sorry about that, I think I've clarified and put in a desired output. Please let me know if something specific isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in row 3 of the desired output. NEW_BAL should be 220.34 - 210 = 10.34.

You can use `base::Reduce` to do a cumulative sum after flipping the sign of TransAmount using C/D:

```
df$TransAmount <- ifelse(df$`X.C.D.`=="C", -df$TransAmount, df$TransAmount)
do.call(rbind, by(df, df$ACCOUNT, function(x) {
    x$NEW_BAL <- Reduce(`+`, x$TransAmount[-1], x$BALANCE[1]+x$TransAmount[1], accumulate=TRUE)        
    x
}))
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[X.C.D.=='C', TransAmount := -TransAmount][, 
    NEW_BAL := Reduce(`+`, TransAmount[-1L], BALANCE[1L]+TransAmount[1L], accumulate=TRUE), by=ACCOUNT]
DT
```

output:

```
         TransAmount X.C.D. ACCOUNT  BALANCE  NEW_BAL
500000.1     -110.00      C  500000   130.34    20.34
500000.2      200.00      D  500000   130.34   220.34
500000.3     -210.00      C  500000   130.34    10.34
500009        -83.07      C  500009 -1079.00 -1162.07
500026       -113.49      C  500026   112.63    -0.86
500041.6      -39.74      C  500041   179.20   139.46
500041.7      -39.74      C  500041   179.20    99.72
500051         80.00      D  500051  -959.93  -879.93
```

data:

```
df <- read.csv(text="TransAmount,'C/D',ACCOUNT,BALANCE
110,C,500000,130.34
200,D,500000,130.34
210,C,500000,130.34
83.07,C,500009,-1079 
113.49,C,500026,112.63
39.74,C,500041,179.2 
39.74,C,500041,179.2 
80,D,500051,-959.93", header=TRUE)
DT <- df
```